# Jenkins REST API

Tags: api, rest, jenkins

I have a task to use Jenkins; REST API and we are trying to add the POST URL or script from the REST API into Jenkins in the HTTP Request Field of Jenkins however I cant figure out how to configure Jenkins so that we can add that field. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using http-request-plugin?
In this case, from its Github page: "This plugin does a HTTP/HTTPS request to a speficied URL with the build parameters automatically part of the payload as key/value pairs.". So you should use build parameters: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build

Comment: Thank you I never installed a Plugin either so I may need some help here. I see that we need to install the HTTP Request not only under the build. Do I need to install  a separate plug in I guess?

Comment: It seems you have the plugin correctly installed. You can do this: 1. Go to the project configuration. 2. Click "This build is parametrized". 3. Configure the parameters you want to send in the POST request (type "text"). 4. Build the project. 5. Go to the HTTP Request configuration and choose "Yes" in "Pass build parameters to the url". The build parameters will be sent in the POST request.

Comment: I'm sorry, configure the HTTP Request (5) and then build (4)

Comment: Thank you!!! I am working on Implementing this. Hopefully it will be a smooth one!

Comment: Alright I am stuck now....Please help. Here is a picture of POST request in a REST API and a picture of the Jenkins build parameter. The request is working in the external REST client but when I import the payload to the build parameter in Jenkins I get a bad syntax error. Everything has to be done in JSON

Comment: If the plugin doesn't fit your needs (it looks akward), you can use `curl` to execute the request. Could you add more information? What data do you have to send in the request? What do you want to do with the response?

Comment: The POST request in a REST API the Jenkins build parameters arent working. The request is working in the external REST client but when I import the payload to the build parameter in Jenkins I get a bad syntax error. Everything has to be done in JSON –